# In Notepad++ how to change the highlighting style of substrings found using search/replace

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, visual-styles

I have trouble spotting the gray highlight applied to a small substring found using the search/replace feature and would like to change the highlight to a color that stands out better for me, like hot pink. Where is that particular style setting found?

Answer (score 3):

In **Settings->Style Configurator** select **Global Styles->Selected text colour** and there select the colour you want

Answer (score 2):

Settings > Style Configurator > make sure the correct theme is selected in 'Select Theme' drop down. On the Language list, go all the way down to 'Search result', then select the relevant Style you want to change from the list of Styles.